# Help, I have a badly soldered plug cable, will it work if I plug it in, will it not electrocute me?

Tags: power-supply, soldering

[image]I wanted to solder a plug wire, but some copper filaments didn't stick to the tin, will I get electrocuted if I plug it into the outlet?[image]

Comment: It sounds to me that you shouldn't take any risk.

Comment: Having any exposed mains is potentially deadly.

Comment: That sounds like a rather bad idea.  Normally mains connections aren't soldered anyway, so it's unclear what you are doing or if the attempt was even appropriate.

Comment: post a picture of the connection. Impossible to say without seeing...

Comment: Are you planning to use it like this? Without even some insulating tape around?

Comment: Why you're even considering plugging that into mains is beyond me. Mains power is no joke. Fire and death are real risks.

Comment: You do realize that **solder is just as conductive as wire** right? You have no insulation there, even if you did get every strand *inside* the solder, the solder being exposed is just as dangerous. **JUST THROW THE CABLE AWAY**. People in my industry call those suicide cables for a reason.

Comment: ho ho ho.  Don't do anything.  I wouldn't worry about the loose strands.  The uninsulated copper seems to be a problem.  You've understood the conductor part, but completely ignored the insulator part.

Comment: It is not a network cable, it is a power cable for a speaker. I do not understand why it is dangerous, the end of the power cable is factory welded to that yellow thing.

Comment: It's something get gets plugged into the wall, right? That would be why it's dangerous. I'm guessing that "yellow thing" is supposed to be inside a speaker or something else you wouldn't touch?

Answer (score 2):

Soldering a mains AC cable sounds bad. It's even worse if you have left some of the strands out of the joint. I have met the following especially dangerous case: One has soldered the thin copper strands of a wire only to keep them together when he tightens the screw in the connector plug. The joint will invariably get loose because the solder will slowly flow out of the joint under the pressure. It can take weeks or months but finally the resistance is so high that the joint gets hot and can cause a fire if the current is several amperes.

ADD: Just saw the afterwards inserted picture. My guidance is: **Stop! Do not plug it! You can kill yourself or some other and burn your house.** Get competent local help. Making a joint to a mains AC cord is strictly forbidden in some countries. Even if the job was well done (this one in your photo is crap) the result would invalidate insurances there.

You have been lucky enough to have been able to get warnings before funerals. Do not expect your luck continues if you use that cord.

Comment: it is not a network cable it is a power cable for a speaker.

Comment: molo, read the comments.  Best it blows a fuse/breaker.  Worst fire, death, destruction!  Step away from the soldering iron.  You are dangerous!

Comment: It looks like you are going to use it to supply the mains AC to some device. No matter if it's a speaker. No self respecting electrician can accept joints this  bad. We have no idea how you thought to insulate it if the joint were good. Frightening. As said: STOP, DO NOT USE IT, GET COMPETENT LOCAL HELP!